# NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup

Tags: linux, drivers, raid, hp

We have `HP DL360 G8` and trying to install CentOS7 and getting this error before it start installing package so installation is never getting complete.. it just going on and on with this error, we have tried to upgrade firmware of `HPVSA` RAID controller too

```
[  175.185716] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s! [hpvsa/4:958]
[  203.189583] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s! [hpvsa/4:958]
[  231.192973] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s! [hpvsa/4:958]
```

Update - CentOS 5/6 working fine, only C7 has issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this on HP DL360 G8 servers which were using multiple fiber channel controllers and multipath to attach several hundred SAN disks to a server.

The problem was that the kernel was booted with a serial console enabled and running at 9600 bps.

When the large number of drives was being discovered, a lot of verbose output was being dumped to the console.  The slow serial console could not keep up with the messages and the soft lockup would occur.

Check `/etc/default/grub` for lines that look like:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL="serial console"
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=9600"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,9600"
```

If you need to maintain a serial console, change 9600 to 115200:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL="serial console"
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=115200"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200"
```

Then reinstall grub with `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

If you don't need a serial console, you can remove `GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND` and update the other two lines and reinstall grub:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0"
```

You may have other parameters in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`, in which case you want to be careful to make sure that you only change the console so that you aren't making other changes which could negatively impact your system.